# Facebook posting of my website doesn't parse OpenGraph tags correctly

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

When I link my site on Facebook, it correctly shows the OpenGraph information in the preview for the posting, but when submitted, it gets lost. If I click the 'Like' button at the bottom of the Linter tool for my page however, it displays correctly on my wall.

Page Being Linked: http://horadric.info/news

Linter: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fhoradric.info%2Fnews

I've tried a few guides' suggestions, such as the xmlns additions to my HTML tag, removing admins/app_id, and a few other things.

It used to work before a week ago, and recently it's been failing.  I figure it's probably an error on Facebook's end, but I'd like some confirmation.

Comment: same problem here...someone found solution?